# How to detect key presses in flutter without a RawKeyboardListener

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard-events

I'm trying to detect key presses like "Enter", "Delete" and "Backspace" within flutter. My issue with using a **`RawKeyboardListener`** is that it takes focus away from any child widgets.

For example

```
RawKeyboardListener(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
  onKey: handleKey,
  child: TextField()
)
```

This makes it impossible to detect both key presses and use the **`Textfield`** at the same time.

Does anyone have a alternative way for detecting key presses.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following from dart_html:

```
    window.onKeyPress.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
      print(e.charCode.toString() + " " + new String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    });
```

Comment: It's not working in iOS

Answer (score 13):

Flutter has a keyboard service that provides Flutter with raw key events from hardware keyboards, and you can ask this service to give you key events as well.

A benefit of this approach is that it doesn't prevent existing Flutter focus nodes from receiving events, so you don't have to manually handle keyboard event propagation.

This works on desktop, but note that it doesn't work for mobile (iOS / Android).

You can add a listener to this service like so:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.addHandler(_onKey);
```

...where `_onKey` is a `bool Function(KeyEvent)`. Here's an example event handler:

```dart
bool _onKey(KeyEvent event) {
  final key = event.logicalKey.keyLabel;

  if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
    print("Key down: $key");
  } else if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
    print("Key up: $key");
  } else if (event is KeyRepeatEvent) {
    print("Key repeat: $key");
  }

  return false;
}
```

See here for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/HardwareKeyboard/addHandler.html

Note that this event handler will always receive key events, even if a text box is currently in focus.

---

Here's an example of using this technique in a widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// ...

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // ...
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // ...

  bool _onKey(KeyEvent event) {
    final key = event.logicalKey.keyLabel;

    if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
      print("Key down: $key");
    } else if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
      print("Key up: $key");
    } else if (event is KeyRepeatEvent) {
      print("Key repeat: $key");
    }

    return false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.addHandler(_onKey);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.removeHandler(_onKey);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not working in iOS

Comment: @ShailendraMadda as far as I know keyboard events can be emitted by physical keyboards on desktop devices and will not work with virtual keyboard on iOS and Android

Comment: Then how does the flutter handle the key events on iOS as `RawKeyboardListener` is limited to Android? @Arenukvern

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dart:ui` and set method `window.onKeyData` in `initState` in a stateful widget

Be careful with that method as if you have any focusable nodes on the screen you will need to pass events to them too, otherwise, for example, TextField will not work.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    window.onKeyData = (final keyData) {
      if (keyData.logical == LogicalKeyboardKey.escape.keyId) {
        widget.onPressed();

        return true;
      }

      /// Let event pass to other focuses if it is not the key we looking for
      return false;
    };
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    window.onKeyData = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: you can improve that by also testing the key event like so `keyData.type == KeyEventType.up` to not have the function called multiple times.

Comment: It's not working in iOS

Comment: Using `window` from `dart:ui` is deprecated now