# Is it possible to use GestureDetector for PC and Web in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need that when I click on any part of the screen, certain actions occur. I do it in the following way:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child:
      Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () {

/// My stuff

    },
            child: Container(
…
```

This works on the Android version. I have plans to make a PC and web version of this application. I want my user to have two options that do the same thing:

1. Click with the mouse on any part of the screen.
2. Press Enter or Space

How to do it?

Comment: What's preventing you from trying it out? GestureDetectors work the same on PC and web. And this answers your second part: [How to detect key presses in flutter without a RawKeyboardListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870688/how-to-detect-key-presses-in-flutter-without-a-rawkeyboardlistener)

Answer (score -1):

you need also to give the gesture detector an expanded widget as child then a container as a child of expanded like this

```
GestureDetector(
    child: Expanded(
        child: Container(
               color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
))),
```

GestureDetector is clickable only if it contains childs so use Expanded to fix it